# Issue linking CSS to HTML file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I can't figure out how to link a `CSS` file to my `HTML` file.

I'm am using Visual Studio Code, Python, and Flask to do this

My project directory is like this:

```
- templates
   - home.html
   - style.css
- app.py
```

**home.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='assets/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  </head>

  <body>
  ...
  </body>
```

**style.css**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
header {
    background-color: #333333;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
h1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color:cadetblue
}
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("home.html")
```

I tried using the templates folder, it didn't work

I tried without using the templates folder, it didn't work.

No error is raised, but the page just doesn't has the `CSS` style, for example the **h1** tags keep being black with the default font, and they should be blue with the *Times New Roman Font*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In flask, your style.css file should be inside the 'static' folder. Then in your Html file you should link it like this:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you used `assets/style.css`, but there is no assets folder in templates, so the css cannot be found.
You can connect CSS files directly in HTML files using relative paths

`<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>`

Comment: Thanks, But, Sadly, I had already tried that, thats a solution i found in [medium](https://medium.com/), but it didnt work.